# Multiple Instance issue of WSO2 (version 5.8) with Claim

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently, We are using WSO2(v5.8) in our development environment. We have used all the soap request almost of WSO2 - tenant creation, service provider, user store, and claim as well. All the soap requests are working fine. But in case of Claim : the problem is , it created successfully and updated successfully using soap request without any error. When we are going to see the new added claim on wso2 console then the newly added claims are not displaying under claims. After sometime the claims are available, which means we are able to see the newly added claim and we can use it with service provider also.

But most of the time is not displaying. I think the claims are not synced properly in case of multiple instances running of WSO2. Somebody help highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically WSO2 Identity Server used distributed caching to utilize the above-mentioned advantages as well as to minimize the coherence problem. However, in newer deployment patterns where the network is not tightly controlled, distributed caching fails in unexpected ways. Hence, we no longer recommend using distributed caching. Instead, it is recommended to have local caches.

Refer to this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Setting+Up+Deployment+Pattern+1) to get further information about deployment patterns.

In order to enable localcaches, Please check whether you have enabled this property in /repository/conf/carbon.xml file

```
 <ForceLocalCache>true</ForceLocalCache>
```

For clustered nodes, enabling this property enables local cache invalidations.

[update]

There is a similar issue already reported regarding claims are not listed or not synced properly in a clustered environment when forcelocalcache is enabled. You can refer to the git issue [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/5015). This issue is fixed with Identity Server 5.9.0

Comment: Will  <ForceLocalCache>true</ForceLocalCache> resolve my issue ?

Comment: hey ,I reviewed my conbon.xml file under config package. This attribute is by default true. But still getting the issue.

Comment: Does this issue persist after restarting server?

Comment: yes Piraveena Paralogarajah its' persist after restarting the server too

Comment: There is a similar issue reported in IS 5.8.0. Please refer to the git issue https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/5015. It is fixed in the latest IS versions

Comment: In which version its fixed . Could you please share with me the version

Comment: Identity Server 5.9.0

Comment: @PiraveenaParalogarajah can you update the GitHub issue and the other details as part of your answer? That would be helpful for anyone coming across the same issue in future.

Comment: @Farasath, thanks for pointing out that. I have updated the answer